# yank to register in a map expression

Tags: key-bindings

I have this mapping that starts a substitute command with the selected text prefilled:

```
xnoremap <Leader>s "vy:% s#\v<C-R>v#<C-R>v#g<left><left>
```

When I select the word `foo` and then press `<leader>s`, I get `:% s#\vfoo#foo|#g` (with `|` showing the cursor position).

But this is not what I want for multiline selections. In this case I want to start a substitution within the selected range.

I have tried this:

```
xnoremap <expr><Leader>s ("vy && getreg('v') =~ '\n') ? ':s###g<left><left><left>' : ':% s#\v<C-R>v#<C-R>v#g<left><left>'
```

When I use this mapping, I get this error:

```
E114: Missing quote: "vy && getreg('v') =~ '\n') ? ':s###g<80>kl<80>kl<80>kl' : ':% s#
\v^Rv#^Rv#g<80>kl<80>kl'
```

I think `"vy` is not allowed here. Using the yank command (`:yank`) does not help:

```
xnoremap <expr><Leader>s (:yank v && getreg('v') =~ '\n') ? ':s###g<left><left><left>' : ':% s#\v<C-R>v#<C-R>v#g<left><left>'
```

```
E121: Undefined variable: :yank
```

`<cmd>yank v` doesn't help either.

And I can't find a `yank()` function.

What's the right way to achieve what I want?

Comment: have you tried escaping the `"` in your original command? For the second mapping, you would need to quote the `:yank v` command. And finally getregion() should also be available on neovim, I think it was merged there as well

Comment: `\"vy` results in an invalid expression. With `':yank v'` or `'<cmd>yank v'` I get no error but yanking does not happen. Oh, you are right about Neovim. I had to upgrade my prerelease version.

Comment: Please post answers in answers, not the question body. I've rolled back that update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you need, I have following in my config:

```
xnoremap <space>% y:%s/<C-r>=escape(getreg(), '^~$/\*.[]')->split("\n")->join('\n')<CR>//g<left><left>
```

which uses default register and then escapes special chars and convert literal newlines to `\n`.

*UPD*

1. if selection is multiline, should search and replace within selection line range
2. otherwise should search whole buffer with prefilled search and replace part with selected text

Using `setcmdline` and `getreg()`:

```
xnoremap <space>% y:<C-r>=(getreg() =~ '\n') ? setcmdline("'<,'>s###g", 8) ?? "" : setcmdline("%s#".getreg()."#".getreg()."#g", getreg()->len()*2+5) ?? ""<CR>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a nice mapping but it doesn't do what I want. For multiline selections, I want to substitute a string within that selection, not the whole selection itself.

Comment: The range is the issue, IIUC.

Comment: @MaxGyver, indeed I read it wrong. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

I have found this commit: [patch 9.1.0120: hard to get visual region using Vim script · vim/vim@3f905ab](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/3f905ab3c4f66562f4a224bf00f49d98a0b0da91)

This solution works only in vim >= 9.1.0120 and Neovim's nightly prerelease build:

```
xnoremap <expr><Leader>s  mode() ==# 'v' && getregion(getpos('v'), getpos('.'), #{ type: mode() })->len() == 1 ? '"vy:% s#\v<C-R>v#<C-R>v#g<left><left>' : ':s###g<left><left><left>'
```

But I'm still looking for a backwards compatible mapping.